# Null-homotopic cellular loops are elementary null-homotopic?

Tags: gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

I've got a 2-dimensional cell complex $X$ and a cellular closed loop $l \subset X$ that I happen to know is null-homotopic in $X$.

There are some very simple sorts of homotopies of cellular loops (or more generally paths) in a 2-complex that I have seen referred to as elementary homotopies.  Namely, elementary homotopies involve either removing/adding redundant parts of a path in the 1-skeleta (where you just drive down a road and come straight back on the same road) as well as removing/adding parts of the path that go around the boundary of a 2-cell.

Is $l$ necessarily null-homotopic through a sequence of elementary homotopies?  This seems intuitively clear, but I can't think of a proof or reference.

[For what it is worth, in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.3912.pdf) draft of a book by Everitt he uses this terminology of elementary homotopies in sections 1.2.4 and 1.2.5.]

Edit: If it is of any help, my particular 2-complex $X$ has the property that every 2-cell is attached via an embedded loop.

Comment: You'll need to define "elementary" as you can't expect people to click links to read a book, before answering your question.  There are various restrictions you can put on homotopies, depending on your goals.

Comment: @RyanBudney I do define elementary homotopies (the sentence starting with "Namely,...").  The link is just there to indicate to anyone interested that I am not just pulling the terminology out of thin air.  I'll move the link lower down in the question.

Comment: If your $X$ is the geometric realization of a simplicial set, maybe you can use simplicial approximation and the fact that triangulations of a 2-disc are collapsible.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood your question.  If your 2-cells are incident to only finitely many 1-cells then I think the answer is yes, and is basically implicit from the group presentation of $\pi_1 X$, provided you follow-through the proof about how canonical-forms work in free groups, etc.   But if you allow relatively wild 2-complexes then I think the answer will be no, these elementary homotopies are not enough.  But perhaps you are looking for a more direct argument, avoiding all the machinery?

Comment: My space is the geometric realization of a simplicial set if I further triangulate the 2-cells and my original thought was that this should follow from some approximation, although I couldn't seem to turn that into a proof.  My 2-cells are all incident to a finite number of 1-cells and if I knew that a van Kampen diagram existed in my context (where the presentation is infinite) then I could follow through the approach @RyanBudney mentions.  I was hoping for a direct proof.